# UICollectionView SupplementaryViews for Empty Sections

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a collection view that imitates a scatter plot by using a custom layout object.

I'm using the number of sections to reflect the x values, and the number of rows in section to represent the number of y values per x value. I've also got another protocol method that asks for the value of the Ys, but thats not relevant.

Anyway, it is entirely possible that a particular section has 0 data points. However, I'd still like that section to display a supplementary view, but I am finding that this method:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is not being called in the empty sections. I guess it makes sense since the indexpath doesn't really exist.

Note: I am using a custom layout, not a flowlayout, so I don't think the header/footer views apply here.

Anyway, does anyone have any insights into how I can add a supplementary view to an empty section?

Comment: Hi Sean, Did you ever get a solution to this?